# Why $\gamma$ in regularization term of XGBoost is defined as minimum loss reduction (not minimum squared loss reduction) and not substracted?

Tags: boosting, regularization, ridge-regression, lagrange-multipliers

From the source https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/model.html I guess that the mean-squared error is optimized subjected to a constraint of minimum loss reduction. It appears like optimization using Lagrange multiplier to bear solution $\Sigma w^2_j = \gamma T$ but why the $\gamma$ in https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html is mentioned as minimum loss reduction, not minimum squared loss reduction, and the regularization term $\Omega(f_t)$ written as $\Omega(f_t)=\frac{1}{2}\lambda\Sigma w^2_j+\gamma T$, not $\Omega(f_t)=\frac{1}{2}\lambda(\Sigma w^2_j-\gamma T)$?

Comment: Maybe the optimization actually has two constraints : $\Sigma w^2_j=0$ and $T=0$. The source here http://courseprojects.souravsengupta.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/eXtreme-Gradient-Boosting.pdf mentioned that both $\lambda$ and $\gamma$ are Lagrangian multipliers. I'm just confused with the constraint $T=0$ because it's only satisfied on the last iteration.

Comment: I find that the regularization term $\Omega(f)=\frac{1}{2}\lambda\Sigma w^2_j+\gamma T$ is related to augmented Lagrangian method here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Lagrangian_method...